# Php insert to mysql variable values from inputs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

How to add to mysql e.g. 4 fields and another time e.g. 120 fields? I mean I got script who create inputs, and I want to add that to mysql, but in mysql I can only add as many values ​​as I set.

There example : `id`,`name`,`1`,`2`,`3` but I want that these values ​​are not limited in 1 record.

And example  : set `id`,`name`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`...`,`2000` in my script who create inputs.

```
<form method="POST" action="api.php">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" class="admininput">
  <input type="text" name="image[]" class="admininput">
  <input type="hidden" name="movie[]" value="0" class="admininput">
  <input type="text" name="seasioncount[]" class="admininput"> 
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="sectioncount[]" class="admininput">        
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 1000;
    var wrapper         = $(".inputs"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field"); 

    var x = 1; 
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="serial[]" class="admininput""/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: If when you talk about values you refer to columns, there is no way to have unlimited columns in a MySQL (or even SQL) table. Maybe you need a diferent RDBMS (NoSQL). Maybe you are not explaining your problem in a way we can understand it to try to help you

Comment: ok, i'll try to explain what i mean best. I want to make a script in php that will add to the database with a variable number of columns from inputs. Someone advised me to do it in json, but I dont have idea how to do it.

Comment: You’re using flat-file thinking instead of relational. You don’t add columns (fields) willy-nilly on the fly. You use two tables that relate to each other.  In your example, session would be a separate table, and each row would refer back to a row in the first table. Research “database normalization” to understand how your tables should be set up.

Comment: i found answer for my question. Thanks for help you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @TimMorton already commented your thinking about the database is a bit wrong.

**From my understanding of your question:**
You've got something with a `name` and something that gets generated that belongs to it.
So a good setup of tables would be like:

**Main table**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | foo  |
|  2 | bar  |
|  3 | baz  |
+----+------+
```

**Generated objects**

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| id | random_field | fk_main |
+----+--------------+---------+
|  1 |        12345 |       1 |
|  2 |          123 |       1 |
|  3 |          455 |       2 |
|  4 |         7677 |       2 |
|  5 |          952 |       3 |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

As you can see, every generated object has a `fk_main` (*foreign-key to main*) which shows where it belongs to (`generated.fk_main == main.id`).

This way you can save as much relational data as you want.

Maybe have a look into this:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

*In the end, you can use queries with `joins` to bring that data together.*